# KubernetesClientException - Operation Get failed

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, netflix-zuul, netflix-ribbon, spring-cloud-kubernetes

I am using Netflix Zuul for an edge service. Once in a while, the PollingServerListUpdater fails one update cycle with a timeout.

Otherwise it runs fine.

Could this be due to an unstable environment or what could be the likely cause?

```
io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Operation: [get]  for kind: [Endpoints]  with name: [routing]  in namespace: [draftcoll-sidr]  failed.
at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:64) ~[kubernetes-client-4.1.0.jar!/:na]
at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:72) ~[kubernetes-client-4.1.0.jar!/:na]
at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.getMandatory(BaseOperation.java:221) ~[kubernetes-client-4.1.0.jar!/:na]
at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.get(BaseOperation.java:177) ~[kubernetes-client-4.1.0.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.ribbon.KubernetesServerList.getUpdatedListOfServers(KubernetesServerList.java:68) ~[spring-cloud-kubernetes-ribbon-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.0.0.RELEASE]
at com.netflix.loadbalancer.DynamicServerListLoadBalancer.updateListOfServers(DynamicServerListLoadBalancer.java:240) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar!/:2.3.0]
at com.netflix.loadbalancer.DynamicServerListLoadBalancer$1.doUpdate(DynamicServerListLoadBalancer.java:62) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar!/:2.3.0]
at com.netflix.loadbalancer.PollingServerListUpdater$1.run(PollingServerListUpdater.java:116) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar!/:2.3.0]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
```

Comment: Are you using spring-cloud-kubernetes? https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes#why-do-you-need-spring-cloud-kubernetes

Comment: Yes, with the discovery client. Added the tag.

Comment: Can you provide logs from Kubernetes API Server at the time of the timeout?

Comment: I can try, it's another department. Hang on :)